# Sbt 1.9.6 project built fails with Scala version 2.12.18 and jdk 1.8

Tags: delta-lake

I am trying to do my first contribution in delta lake open source project.
I followed the [contribution guide](https://github.com/delta-io/delta#intellij-setup) to set up project on IntelliJ but whenever I try to build project it fails with following output error :

```
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:31:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{AppendFiles, DeleteFiles, OverwriteFiles, PendingUpdate, RewriteFiles, Transaction => IcebergTransaction}
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:32:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopTables
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:61:52: not found: type PendingUpdate
[error]   protected abstract class TransactionHelper(impl: PendingUpdate[_]) {
[error]                                                    ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:80:36: not found: type AppendFiles
[error]   class AppendOnlyHelper(appender: AppendFiles) extends TransactionHelper(appender) {
[error]                                    ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:104:35: not found: type DeleteFiles
[error]   class RemoveOnlyHelper(deleter: DeleteFiles) extends TransactionHelper(deleter) {
[error]                                   ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:121:37: not found: type OverwriteFiles
[error]   class OverwriteHelper(overwriter: OverwriteFiles) extends TransactionHelper(overwriter) {
[error]                                     ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:153:33: not found: type RewriteFiles
[error]   class RewriteHelper(rewriter: RewriteFiles) extends TransactionHelper(rewriter) {
[error]                                 ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:27:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{DataFile, DataFiles, FileFormat, PartitionSpec, Schema => IcebergSchema}
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:90:62: not found: type DataFile
[error]       logicalToPhysicalPartitionNames: Map[String, String]): DataFile = {
[error]                                                              ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:89:22: not found: type PartitionSpec
[error]       partitionSpec: PartitionSpec,
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:46:39: not found: type PartitionSpec
[error]       partitionColumns: Seq[String]): PartitionSpec = {
[error]                                       ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:45:22: not found: type IcebergSchema
[error]       icebergSchema: IcebergSchema,
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:23:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{Schema => IcebergSchema}
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:41:67: not found: type IcebergSchema
[error]   def convertDeltaSchemaToIcebergSchema(deltaSchema: StructType): IcebergSchema = {
[error]                                                                   ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:65:28: not found: type DataFile
[error]       deltaLog: DeltaLog): DataFile = {
[error]                            ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:61:22: not found: type PartitionSpec
[error]       partitionSpec: PartitionSpec,
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:321:37: not found: type IcebergTransaction
[error]   protected def createIcebergTxn(): IcebergTransaction = {
[error]                                     ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:31:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.hive.HiveCatalog
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:186:49: not found: type HiveCatalog
[error]   def createHiveCatalog(conf : Configuration) : HiveCatalog = {
[error]                                                 ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:29:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.catalog.{Namespace, TableIdentifier => IcebergTableIdentifier}
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:199:42: not found: type IcebergTableIdentifier
[error]       identifier: SparkTableIdentifier): IcebergTableIdentifier = {
[error]                                          ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:31:43: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{AppendFiles, DeleteFiles, OverwriteFiles, PendingUpdate, RewriteFiles, Transaction => IcebergTransaction}
[warn]                                           ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:31:56: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{AppendFiles, DeleteFiles, OverwriteFiles, PendingUpdate, RewriteFiles, Transaction => IcebergTransaction}
[warn]                                                        ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:31:69: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{AppendFiles, DeleteFiles, OverwriteFiles, PendingUpdate, RewriteFiles, Transaction => IcebergTransaction}
[warn]                                                                     ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:31:85: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{AppendFiles, DeleteFiles, OverwriteFiles, PendingUpdate, RewriteFiles, Transaction => IcebergTransaction}
[warn]                                                                                     ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:31:100: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{AppendFiles, DeleteFiles, OverwriteFiles, PendingUpdate, RewriteFiles, Transaction => IcebergTransaction}
[warn]                                                                                                    ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:31:114: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{AppendFiles, DeleteFiles, OverwriteFiles, PendingUpdate, RewriteFiles, Transaction => IcebergTransaction}
[warn]                                                                                                                  ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConversionTransaction.scala:32:49: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopTables
[warn]                                                 ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConverter.scala:33:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.hive.{HiveCatalog, HiveTableOperations}
[error]        ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConverter.scala:33:48: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.hive.{HiveCatalog, HiveTableOperations}
[warn]                                                ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergConverter.scala:33:61: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.hive.{HiveCatalog, HiveTableOperations}
[warn]                                                             ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:24:8: not found: object shadedForDelta
[error] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.types.{Type => IcebergType, Types => IcebergTypes}
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:51:62: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]   private[delta] def convertStruct(deltaSchema: StructType): IcebergTypes.StructType = {
[error]                                                              ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:43:9: not found: type IcebergSchema
[error]     new IcebergSchema(icebergStruct.fields())
[error]         ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:61:44: not found: type IcebergType
[error]     def transform[E <: DataType](elem: E): IcebergType = elem match {
[error]                                            ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:63:9: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]         IcebergTypes.StructType.of(fields.map { f =>
[error]         ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:68:11: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]           IcebergTypes.NestedField.of(
[error]           ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:75:11: value toList is not a member of Array[Nothing]
[error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toList'?
[error]         }.toList.asJava)
[error]           ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:99:61: not found: value IcebergType
[error]   private[delta] def convertAtomic[E <: DataType](elem: E): IcebergType.PrimitiveType = elem match {
[error]                                                             ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:100:24: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case StringType => IcebergTypes.StringType.get()
[error]                        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:101:22: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case LongType => IcebergTypes.LongType.get()
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:102:48: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case IntegerType | ShortType | ByteType => IcebergTypes.IntegerType.get()
[error]                                                ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:103:23: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case FloatType => IcebergTypes.FloatType.get()
[error]                       ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:104:24: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case DoubleType => IcebergTypes.DoubleType.get()
[error]                        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:105:28: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case d: DecimalType => IcebergTypes.DecimalType.of(d.precision, d.scale)
[error]                            ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:106:25: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case BooleanType => IcebergTypes.BooleanType.get()
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:107:24: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case BinaryType => IcebergTypes.BinaryType.get()
[error]                        ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:108:22: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case DateType => IcebergTypes.DateType.get()
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:109:27: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case TimestampType => IcebergTypes.TimestampType.withZone()
[error]                           ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:110:30: not found: value IcebergTypes
[error]     case TimestampNTZType => IcebergTypes.TimestampType.withoutZone()
[error]                              ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:19:40: Unused import
[warn] import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
[warn]                                        ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:23:43: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{Schema => IcebergSchema}
[warn]                                           ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:24:49: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.types.{Type => IcebergType, Types => IcebergTypes}
[warn]                                                 ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergSchemaUtils.scala:24:70: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.types.{Type => IcebergType, Types => IcebergTypes}
[warn]                                                                      ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:48:7: not found: value PartitionSpec
[error]       PartitionSpec.unpartitioned
[error]       ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:50:21: not found: value PartitionSpec
[error]       val builder = PartitionSpec.builderFor(icebergSchema)
[error]                     ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:148:62: not found: value DataFiles
[error]       logicalToPhysicalPartitionNames: Map[String, String]): DataFiles.Builder = {
[error]                                                              ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:147:22: not found: type PartitionSpec
[error]       partitionSpec: PartitionSpec,
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:151:19: not found: value DataFiles
[error]     var builder = DataFiles
[error]                   ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:155:19: not found: value FileFormat
[error]       .withFormat(FileFormat.PARQUET)
[error]                   ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:187:23: not found: type HiveCatalog
[error]     val catalog = new HiveCatalog()
[error]                       ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:201:30: not found: value Namespace
[error]       case Some(database) => Namespace.of(database)
[error]                              ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:202:17: not found: value Namespace
[error]       case _ => Namespace.empty()
[error]                 ^
[error] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:204:5: not found: value IcebergTableIdentifier
[error]     IcebergTableIdentifier.of(namespace, identifier.table)
[error]     ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:19:40: Unused import
[warn] import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
[warn]                                        ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:20:27: Unused import
[warn] import scala.util.control.NonFatal
[warn]                           ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:27:43: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{DataFile, DataFiles, FileFormat, PartitionSpec, Schema => IcebergSchema}
[warn]                                           ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:27:53: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{DataFile, DataFiles, FileFormat, PartitionSpec, Schema => IcebergSchema}
[warn]                                                     ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:27:64: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{DataFile, DataFiles, FileFormat, PartitionSpec, Schema => IcebergSchema}
[warn]                                                                ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:27:76: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{DataFile, DataFiles, FileFormat, PartitionSpec, Schema => IcebergSchema}
[warn]                                                                            ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:27:91: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.{DataFile, DataFiles, FileFormat, PartitionSpec, Schema => IcebergSchema}
[warn]                                                                                           ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:29:51: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.catalog.{Namespace, TableIdentifier => IcebergTableIdentifier}
[warn]                                                   ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:29:62: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.catalog.{Namespace, TableIdentifier => IcebergTableIdentifier}
[warn]                                                              ^
[warn] /Users/rango/IdeaProjects/delta/iceberg/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/icebergShaded/IcebergTransactionUtils.scala:31:47: Unused import
[warn] import shadedForDelta.org.apache.iceberg.hive.HiveCatalog
[warn]                                               ^
[warn] 25 warnings found
[error] 51 errors found
[error] (iceberg / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 19 s, completed 2023-10-17 18:34:46
[info] shutting down sbt server
```

In build.sbt file :

```
// Scala versions
val scala212 = "2.12.18"
val scala213 = "2.13.8"
```

In project build.properties :

```
sbt.version=1.9.6
```

I've been going through the net tryna solve the problem but haven't succeeded
and I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand the problem and suggest  me a solution to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. Finally i found the java version should be 8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).